# OpenGL use uniform buffer as an array

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I found out that I can use uniform buffers to store multiple variables like this

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

layout (std140) uniform Matrices
{
    mat4 projection;
    mat4 view;
};

uniform mat4 model;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}
```

and treat this data like any other buffer

```
unsigned int uboMatrices
glGenBuffers(1, &uboMatrices);
  
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, uboMatrices);
glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 2 * sizeof(glm::mat4), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
  
glBindBufferRange(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, uboMatrices, 0, 2 * sizeof(glm::mat4));
```

However, I can't seem to find any examples that would allow me to treat such a buffer like an array. Essentially I would like to achieve a global random-access buffer  like this

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

layout (what here?) uniform float[] globalBuffer;

uniform mat4 model;

void main()
{
    ...
}
```

The long term plan is to later produce this array with OpenCL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uniform float[] globalBuffer;` is not a uniform buffer. It is just an array of uniforms. You must set the uniforms with [`glUniform1fv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml).

A [Uniform block](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Interface_Block_(GLSL)#Uniform_blocks) would be:

```c
layout (std140) uniform Foo 
{ 
    float[] globalBuffer; 
}
```

Unfortunately, in this case each array element would be aligned to the size of `vec4`. See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification; 7.6.2.2 Standard Uniform Block Layout](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=168&zoom=100,0,381):

> 4. If the member is an array of scalars or vectors, the base alignment and array stride are set to match the base alignment of a single array element, according to rules (1), (2), and (3), and **rounded up to the base alignment of a `vec4`**.

I recommend to use a [Shader Storage Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object)

```c
layout (std430) buffer Foo
{
    float[] globalBuffer; 
};
```

[OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification; 7.6.2.2 Standard Uniform Block Layout](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=168&zoom=100,0,381):

> Shader storage blocks (see section 7.8) also support the `std140` layout qualifier, as well as a `std430` qualifier not supported for uniform blocks. When using the `std430` storage layout, shader storage blocks will be laid out in buffer storage identically to uniform and shader storage blocks using the `std140` layout, **except** that the base alignment and stride of arrays of scalars and vectors in rule 4 and of structures in rule 9 **are not rounded up a multiple of the base alignment of a `vec4`**.